# R and MongoDB: Array is stored as an object with indexes as keys

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I'm pulling in JSON data from a provider and adding it to mongodb using R. I plan on using R and Shiny to display the data in the future. I'm currently having an issue right now though where I place the data into a JSON Object and insert it into MongoDB. It adds the object but places the data one level lower than where I would really like it.

Here is how the data comes in:

```
prettify(jsonKill)
[
    {
        "id" : {
            "timestamp" : 1409785080,
            "machine" : 11966932,
            "pid" : 3144,
            "increment" : 11720074,
            "creationTime" : "2014-09-03T22:58:00Z"
        },
    ...
]
```

Here is my code that adds it to mongodb:

```
library('jsonlite')
library('rmongodb')

m <- mongo.create()
ns <- 'database.collection'
killObject <- fromJSON('http://omitted.because.nda:8000/api/omit')
x <- nrow(killObject)
for(i in 1:x){
  jsonKill <- toJSON(killObject[i:i,])
  bson <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(jsonKill)
  mongo.insert(m, ns, bson)
  paste("Inserting Record: ", i)
}
cursor <- mongo.find(m, ns, bson)
while(mongo.cursor.next(cursor)){
  value <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor)
  list <- mongo.bson.to.list(value)
  str(list)
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54081299d5ec83d046d05766"),
    "1" : {
        "id" : {
            "timestamp" : 1409756219,
            "machine" : 2364985,
            "pid" : 9076,
            "increment" : 1079972,
            "creationTime" : "2014-09-03T14:56:59Z"
        },
    ...
}
```

What I'm aiming for is to do `db.collection.find({"id.pid" : $gt1})` or an index with `mongo.index.create(m, ns, {"id.pid"}, mongo.index.unique)` something to that effect, not necessarily the `id` key, but one or more of the keys not displayed here.

Comment: is it possible that the service returns an array of json documents instead of an object? does it have multiple id-fields? please provide a full response leaving out only actually redundant parts.

Comment: The service returns an array of objects. Previously, when I would insert the Object the entire Object would go in as 1 big object. I'm just looking to have individual objects that I don't have to references by `"#.key.key"`. This was remedied with my for loop, breaking it apart and inserting each object and all of its children individually, but I'm still having the issue of that #'d field getting in the way of my query/create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that rmongodb currently features a bug that will handicap usage of arrays.

---

**R:**

```
library(rmongodb)

m <- mongo.create()

json <- '{"array":[{"a":1},{"b":2}]}'
bson <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(json)

mongo.insert(m, "database.collection", bson)
```

**MongoDB shell:**

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("540825d68a271f234b6d62d2"),
        "array" : {
                "1" : {
                        "a" : 1
                },
                "2" : {
                        "b" : 2
                }
        }
}
```

---

For that purpose I developed a package ([rmongodbHelper](https://github.com/joyofdata/rmongodbHelper)) that provides a workaround for that issue:

**R:**

```
library(devtools)
install_github("joyofdata/rmongodbHelper")
library(rmongodbHelper)

json <- '{"array":[{"a":1},{"b":2}]}'
bson <- rmongodbHelper::json_to_bson(json)

mongo.insert(m, "database.collection", bson)
```

**MongodB shell:**

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("540826738a271f234b6d62d4"),
        "array" : [
                {
                        "a" : 1
                },
                {
                        "b" : 2
                }
        ]
}
```

---

You can find further information on this package and on using MongoDB with R on my web-site:

[MongoDB - State of the R](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mongodb-state-of-the-r-rmongodb/)

---

Keep in mind that MongoDB cannot store bare arrays - only objects - which themselves may contain arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Now [it works](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/pull/51) out of the box. `mongo.bson.from.list`  now can convert unnamed lists into arrays.